# Seek a command to move or rename or cut a file on windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio, batch-file, command

I want to move / cut a file on Windows (PS: the orginal path and destination are on the same drive.)
I know `xcopy` can copy a file, but I don't know how to cut a file with it. And it came to me the command of `rename` which is the function name of cutting a file in C/C++.

I tried this, [rename command](https://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-file-from-command-line/), but it seems it just renames files under a same folder, so it can't do cutting.

And I also don't want to do copy+delete the orignal one work, because a real cut a more effective since it just changes the file's position reference in the directory tree.

Edit: I'm seeking a command working for VisualStudio Post Build Event. It seems `Move-Item` doesn't work for that.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? PowerShell? CMD? Did you try to search for it? It takes only seconds to find [Move-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: @Olaf, thanks! I searched "cut a file with xcopy" or something like that, didn't find anything useful. And, I just tried Move-Item as you adviced, it failed with `Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` I think I should check and delete the existed one.

Comment: @Olaf, actually, I'm seeking a command working for VisualStudio Post Build Event. But Move-Item seems not work for that. It pops an error, seems VS doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: `because a real cut a more effective since it just changes the file's position reference in the directory tree` that's exactly, what the `move` command does. See `move /?`

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @Olaf's hint. I just find the command `move`, and with the help of `if exist ... del`, it works well for visual studio build event

```
IF EXIST "destionation\$(TargetFileName)" (DEL /F "destionation\$(TargetFileName)")
Move $(TargetPath) destionation\$(TargetFileName)
```